# transitionFadeWithDuration - No known class method

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I was handed a code that I am expected to get running but I am having some trouble because It is my first time doing any ios development or objective c using cocoa2d-iphone. I am having a problem with the transition fade with duration function where it tells me there is no known class method. My button push triggers this change so I'll be providing the function for it.

I checked and saw that I needed to provide the class name and not the instance so I did. Besides that I didn't find much information.

```
-(void) backPressed:(CCButton *)button
{
  if(deviceStarted) 
  {
    deviceStarted = NO;
    [[InputManager instance] stopReadings];
  }
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainMenuScene scene] 
  withTransition:[CCTransition transitionFadeWithDuration:0.4f]];
}

The error I get is:
No known class method for selector 'transitionFadeWithDuration:'
CalibrateScene.m
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that there is no method transitionFadeWithDuration in the class CCTransition. Thats what the error states.

Which version of cocos2d-iphone are you using?

This worked for me in version 2.x:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.4f scene:[MainMenuScene scene]]];
```

In version 3.x replaceScene was replaced with presentScene. There this wirks for me:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentScene:[MainMenuScene scene] withTransition:[CCDefaultTransition transitionFadeWithDuration:0.4f]];
```